# Split text box text value in before "@" in Javascript

Tags: javascript, java, jsp, servlets

Here i have txtemailid and txtlogin(read only) what i type in txtemailid before @ text it will directly go to txtlogin text box when i will happen means when i type something in email text box and next click to mouse without entering the user. how can i do this java and i take code in java script it's not working

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is better you use keyboard event to make changes on each time a key is pressed.I am doing using `onkeyup`.I prefer `document.getElementById()` rather than `document.form` because it can accurately retrieve it, every time, without caring about what happens to the document in the meantime.You can use either of the two.

[**JSFIDDLE**](https://jsfiddle.net/p0emp3rm/)

Here is the code:

```js
function myFunction() {
  var text1 = document.getElementById("txtEmailId").value;
  var result = text1.split("@");
  document.getElementById("txtLoginname").value = result[0];
}
```

```html
<form>
  Enter Email: <input type="text" id="txtEmailId" onkeyup="myFunction()" /><br/><br/> Login Name: <input type="text" id="txtLoginname" /><br/><br/>
</form>
```